# SQL Query- Find row where all entries are non Null

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table "interesting_table" where I want to find all rows where all entries are non null.

I was trying

```
select * from interesting_table where * is not NULL ;
```

It doesn't work because * is not recognized as a column. How can I modify this without listing all the columns?

Comment: there is no easy way. either specify all the columns or use dynamic sql to construct your statement.

Comment: You have to actually list the columns, and do the is not null check on every one, separated by AND conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Joel and vkp. Question can be closed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1) Use a function like `CONCAT` that will return null if any of parameters is null

```
select *
from interesting_table
where concat(data1, data2) is not null;
```

2) Use `NATURAL JOIN` with the same table. If any of the columns is NULL, the JOIN will fail for that row.

```
select t1.* 
from interesting_table t1
natural join interesting_table t2;
```

If the table contains duplicates, you might need to use DISTINCT.

Demo: http://rextester.com/NRSDM90436